# Disable ARP while data transfer

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, arp

I am sending data over PC1 to PC2, both are Linux 2.6 kernel machines. This transfer will take a couple of hours. The ARP cache stale timeout is set to 50 seconds in PC1. So during data transfer, every 50 seconds the PC1 sends ARP request to PC2 (since the arp cache expires in PC1). But theoretically, since data transfer is ongoing it is not required to send an ARP request to PC2 (Since PC1 knows PC2 is still there).

How is it possible to disable the expiry of ARP entry of PC2 inside PC1 (if the data transfer to PC2 is still ongoing)?

Note: I want to disable the arp-cache expiry for only for the PC2 ARP cache entry during transfer to PC2. After transfer let the ARP entry expire.

Comment: *Why* would you bother to do this? It's not as if the occasional ARP packet is going to have any impact on your transfer speed.

Comment: @Kristof Provost  The kernel will stop sending the packets if the ARP reply somehow does not come. This happens due to some network issue here. I want to make the transfer continue even if I dont receive ARP reply (Yes - I need a kind of hack - in the kernel , or in my application to do this)

Comment: If there is a network issue, will not the transfer be having trouble as well?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg This network issue is a custom issue from a network switch. The swich has a bug that wont send back proxy ARP reply some times. So the PC1  wont get the proxy ARP reply for PC2.(I want my data transfer to continue with the faulty switch - that is not replaced purposefully).

Comment: At a rate of 812 packets per second on "old" 10 mbit ethernet, respectively 40600 packets per 50 seconds, the 2 packets exchanged in ARP make up about 0.002% (10/100 times less on 100/1000 mbit). Packet loss due to cable noise is, depending on the quality of your components 10-20 times higher. So what's the gain?

Comment: @Damon . If I dont get the ARP reply (after a couple of tries), the data transfer to PC2 stops. I want my in-house custom data transfer application to work around this faulty switch (The only issue with this switch is that it wont send Proxy APR reply) . I am looking for some updates in the kernel that will let the data transfer continue. I want the hack only for the duration of data transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a new switch.

Really. Don't try to work around hardware issues by fooling around in the kernel.

If you really insist on getting this working, just set up static ARP entries. They don't time out.

Comment: I have more time than money :-) .

Answer (score 0):

In general, expiration of ARP improves connection reliability, not vice versa.
Suppose PC2 changes its MAC address for some reason. Within a network segment it may not make much sense, but in more complicated networks it does. With ARP, PC1 will soon enough learn the new MAC and proceed. Without it, it will still try to talk to the old MAC.

This said, static ARP (`arp -s`) can easily be used to tell PC1 what's PC2's MAC address, for all eternity (or the next boot, whichever comes first).